# character array and for loop error

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, methods

For a class I am taking, I am to create a program that tests whether a string is a palindrome. We were supposed to just use an 8 character string every time and hard-code it that way, but I wanted to get above and beyond and make something to test any string. Unfortunately, this code seems to aways return true, and I'm honestly not sure why.

```
    public static boolean palindromeTest(String input){
    //This portion declares variables necessary for testing, and modifies them if necessary.
    int inputLength=input.length();
    char[] Chars=input.toCharArray();
    for(int j=0; j<inputLength; j++){
        Character.toLowerCase(Chars[j]); //makes all characters in input lower case
        //This portion performs the palindrome test
    }
    if(inputLength%2>0){ //if length is odd
        inputLength=(inputLength-1)/2;
        for(int i=0; i>0; i++){
            if(Chars[i]!=Chars[inputLength-i]) //tests equality first and last in pairs via for loop
                return false; //break;
        }
    }else{ //if length is even
        inputLength=(inputLength)/2;
        for(int i=0; i>0; i++){
            if(Chars[i]!=Chars[inputLength-i]) //tests equality first and last in pairs via for loop
                return false; //break;
        }
    }
    return true; //if all tests are passed, input is indeed a palindrome
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it is because of

```
for(int i=0; i>0; i++){
```

the code inside the for loop will never be executed as i is never greater than 0

**Edit:**
Moreover

```
if(charArray[i]!=charArray[inputLength - i])
```

is kinda wrong, cuz lets say your string is madam, `inputLength = inputLength-1` makes the above condition to check "m" and "d" which not how it should work

the correct solution would be

```
inputLength = inputLength / 2;
int  j= input.length()-1;

for(int i =0; i< inputLength; i++, j--) {

  if(charArray[i]!=charArray[j]) {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: yup, the upper bound on the number of for loop iterations needs to be changed.

Comment: OHHH thanks, I have no idea why I put that, I meant i<inputLength;

Answer (score 0):

the palindrome test method using for loop and char array is as follows:

```
  public static boolean palindromeTest(String input){
             char[] Chars=input.toCharArray();
             for(int i=0,j=Chars.length-1;i<j;i++,j--){
                 if(Chars[i]!=Chars[j]){
                     return false;
                 }
             }
            return true;
            }
```